# Toggle navigation isn't working

Tags: html

I have tried just about everything to get the toggle navigation to work and I have had no luck. Is it just a simple mistake or piece of code I'm missing? I have tried loading different scripts but still nothing.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color: #f2f2f2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#/home" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="img/evodent-logo.png" alt="evodent-logo" style="width:190px;">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#/about" style="color: black;">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#/contact" style="color: black;">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn't work" ?

Comment: when I click on the button, it doesn't respond.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/berets/9spsmLsy/ , here is working the code is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the code is working just fine as is. Make sure that you are including the `bootstrap.min.js` file on your page as well. As the collapsible components in bootstrap require this plugin/file.

Here is the official documentation on the Bootstrap Navbar that mentions that the plugin is required: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

> **Requires JavaScript plugin**
>
> If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view the content within the `.navbar-collapse`.
>
> The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap.